# Type has no construct signatures in TS

Tags: typescript

This is my model :

```
export class User
{
    public email:string ;
    public name:string;
    public phone: string;
    public id:string;
    private _token:string;
    private _tokenExpirationDate:string;
    constructor(email:string,name:string,phone:string,id:string,_token:string,_tokenExpirationDate:string){
        this.name=name;    
        this.email=email;
        this.id=id;
        this.phone=phone;
        this._token=_token;
        this._tokenExpirationDate=_tokenExpirationDate;
```

### }
}

This is were I got the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0n06.png)

Comment: please try to remove "this" keyword before you trying to create the user

Comment: const user1 = new User(.......)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLlyVm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)